# Update address bar value after slider change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a price slider that can be used to filter product results.  It's the ion Range Slider found [here](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html).

When the user has finished dragging the slider, an XMLHttp request is sent to the database and the products refresh without a page reload.

It's at this point that I'd like to update the URL to match the contents of the page. For example if a user accesses the following page:

```
mywebsite.com/a-product-category/
```

And sets the price slider to `$10 - $40`, I'd like the URL to change to:

```
mywebsite.com/a-product-category/10-to-40
```

Is there a simple way to do this in jQuery or Javascript? I've attemped various ways of implementing PushState but it doesn't work for me.  Maybe I'm doing it wrong:

```
if (!this.dragging) {
    window.history.pushState({}, '', '/10-to-40');
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I've created 2 versions of what I'm after, 1 with the `window.history.pushState({}, '', '/10-to-40');` line and one without.

Without the pushState:
(link no longer works)

With the pushState:
(link no longer works)

As you can see, the slider works in the first example but not in the 2nd.  Here is the error I get on the second page:

**SecurityError: The operation is insecure.**

This refers to line 982, the pushState.

Is there a reason it's insecure? Thanks

**EDIT 2:**

It was due to working on a subdomain.  Changing the pushState to a complete URL fixed the issue.

```
if (!this.dragging) {
    window.history.pushState({}, '', 'http://dev.mywebsite.com/a-product-category/10-to-40');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: From a brief test, that code appears to work. Whatever the problem it, it does't seem to be demonstrated by the code you've shared so far.

Comment: have you tried using hashchange?  mywebsite.com/a-product-category/#10-to-40
you can detect hashchange by event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange

Comment: @DeepakDavid — `pushState` is the modern replacement, and the question is about setting the URL, not detecting changes to it.

Comment: right but traditional and easy way to do it is hashchange and it does have an event also to track the URL change

Comment: `pushState` is non-hacky and easy and the code in the question works.

Comment: Hi guys, I've edited the original question with more info.  I've given 2 examples, the error is that the pushState is insecure, but I'm not sure how to remedy that

Comment: Unless it's to do with me working on a subdomain? dev.?

Comment: Yep - changing the code to `window.history.pushState({}, '', 'http://dev.thegiftguru.co.uk/category/10-to-40');` works...